# How can I change offset for some characters in Kivy string?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

How can I set offset for a some characters or words in Kivy? I'd like to obtain something like
[image: The mix of symbol and text]

It consists of 24pt Windings symbol which has offset -18% (to have bigger sign vertically centered relatively smaller font) and 12 pt common font label. It's important to have symbol with the text inline, 'cause really it's the part of a text paragraph.
I've tried to do something like

`string = "[sub][size=45]t[/size][/sub]est"`

But to no avail - Kivy just ignores all previous [] markup commands, i.e. if I use [sub] and [size=...] it always use the last instruction to the basic text, so I cannot have BOTH [sub] and [size=...] rendered.
I know that I can install pango library, fully reinstall Kivy and then I can achieve what I need with [font_features]. The problem is that I will build Android app from this code so I need to keep app as light as possible (it is 30M right now already and starts relatively slowly even at middle-level smartphones).
Moreover, it's quite unobviously how can I add pango library to buildozer and build APK with pango support (and how to turn ON pango text render under Android).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this string in a `Label`, you can also use the `font_size` attribute of the `Label`. Perhaps you could use that attribute to set the `size` for the entire `Label` to the `size` that you want inside the `[sub]` and `[/sub]`, and use markup to adjust the rest of the string. Like this:

```
    t = "[sub]t[/sub][size=12]est[/size]"
    l = Label(text=t, font_size=45, markup=True)
```